# local server with Let's Encrypt SSL certificate

Tags: ssl, certificate, letsencrypt, certbot

I'm running a Confluence server in my local domain that I want to access from the outside using OpenVPN.

Since I want to use the Confluence app, I need to enable SSL and use a cert which is stored in iOS. That rules out my local certificate chain.

I thought of using Let's Encrypt, but I'm not sure whether it's possible to issue certificates for my local domain. I've read various articles that suggest I can do it with a DNS challenge.

I've tried to update my zone.conf with the relevant TXT entry, but the DNS challenge fails with this message:

```
Failed authorization procedure. confluence.brave-vesperia.com (dns-01): 
urn:acme:error:dns  :: DNS problem: SERVFAIL looking up TXT for 
_acme-challenge.confluence.brave-vesperia.com
```

part of my bind config:

```
brave-vesperia.com. IN  SOA brave-vesperia.com. (
        1486898704
        10800
        3600
        604800
        38400 )

_acme-challenge.confluence.brave-vesperia.com. IN TXT "aJ0Y5HyJ0TBmebIqu5TMrQM4ceiZsYe2L1xDHrixdUo"
```

I can confirm that the bind server is running and working properly. I've also restarted it after adding the _acme-challenge part.

Is there anything blatantly wrong with my config? Can I check from the command line why the dns challenge fails?

```
 dig -t txt _acme-challenge.confluence.brave-vesperia.com
```

returns the correct string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For "DNS challenge" your domain DNS records must be public available. LE mechanisms will check your records from public DNS servers.

But your domain not presented anywhere in public area.

`dig -t ns confluence.brave-vesperia.com 8.8.8.8 +short` returns nothing.

`dig -t ns brave-vesperia.com 8.8.8.8 +short` returns nothing.